# Can the .buildignore file be removed from the Yeoman generated Angular app directory with no issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I assume that file is for Grunt's build task, however, there is no configuration for coffee script compiling in the Gruntfile. This seemingly irrelevant file makes me wonder if the maintainers of the Yeoman Angular project put it there for a good reason, which makes me a bit paranoid to straight out remove it.

Comment: I know this is old but it will be installed only if coffee is selected in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can remove it with no worries, especially if you have nothing in it. If you're really worried, move it to a different folder and run a build, then if it fails you can move it back.